# how to covert the string into userdefined class type

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Video

    at Second_project.VideoStore.addVideo(VideoStore.java:10)
    at Second_project.VideoLauncher.main(VideoLauncher.java:20)
```

Comment: Apparently the issue is at `VideoStore.java:10` but since you haven't shared that code, that's all we can say until you [edit] and add the code (as text). Preferably as a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can't really explicitly convert a `String` to a `Video` (or any user-defined type)

However, you could make a constructor for `Video` that accepts a `String` value and creates a `Video` out of it.

You can even define a `toString()` method for `Video` that will return the `String` representation of `Video`

```
public class Video {
    ...
    // String constructor
    public Video(String s){
        //Set some values
        //Ex. videoName = s;
    }
    ...
    // Converts Videos to String
    public String toString(){
        //Return something
        //Ex. Return this.videoName;
    }
}
```